How can I include a WAR and read it in a runnable JAR?
I have a runnable JAR that contains a Java program that runs an embedded Jetty.  The Jetty loads a WAR file as a WebApp and exposes the servlets in the WAR.  This works as intended.
The WAR file is read from a local directory on my test machine.  I want instead to include the WAR file in the runnable JAR and read it with the Java program's setWar() method  so the JAR can be run elsewhere. I have been fiddling with the JAR project's build path and also looking at the maven-assembly-plugin, but so far I have not found a way to do this.  Any suggestions?  Thanks very much.

import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server();
        ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
        connector.setPort(8088);
        server.addConnector(connector);
        WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
        server.setHandler(context);

        context.setWar("/home/dan/jersey-servlet.war");

        try {
            server.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


https://github.com/jetty/jetty-examples might help

Thank you for the suggestion, seenukarthi. -Dan

I have a solution which works well for my requirements although it is not a general case solution.  I have chosen to stage the WAR file to cloud object storage prior to running my JAR, and have the Java program in m JAR download it to /tmp and then pass its path in /tmp to the setWar() method:
context.setWar("/tmp/jersey-servlet.war");
